# What kind of assignment is done in this javascript statement: var api = this.api(), data;

Tags: datatables

There is a Datatables footerCallback example given at this [link](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html).

I am looking at this line of code in particular:

```
var api = this.api(), data;
```

I am not able to understand what would the `, data` portion add to `this.api()`.

Some other examples in Datatables like the second one [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/footerCallback) do not use ", data" portion.

I am thinking adding ", data" in the assignment statement has something to do with JavaScript syntax. I am not thoroughly aware of JavaScript syntaxes, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is two variables are being instantiated at once: `api` and `data`. Since `data` has no assignment, it's value will be `undefined`.

```
 var api = this.api(), data;
```

is the same as writing this:

```
 var api = this.api();
 var data;
```

Comment: @qodesmith : Thanks. But if you look at the code snippet from the example:

$('#example').DataTable( {
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;

looks like variable data is also one of the function parameters. So how can this example declare another variable data within the same function?

Comment: @MonicaLavale In the example you just mentioned, declaring `data` shorthand like that is a no op. It literally does nothing. The parameter `data` will still retain its value.